# What happens to local files when enabling redirection?

Tags: windows

The answer to this seems like it should be obvious but I can't seem to craft search terms to find it.

If a user already has locally stored files in Documents and Desktop, what happens to those files when I initially turn on Folder Redirection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With folder redirection you have a couple options that permit you to adjust permissions, and to relocate content.

[image: folder redirection properties]

See:

- [How to Configure Folder Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782799%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing - The user doesn't see them on their Desktop or Library, those folders are just ignored.

Comment: Not quite.  It depends on the policy.  You can choose the `Move the contents of [FolderName] to the new location` option.  So it can certainly be more than nothing.

Comment: @Zoredache Well that's new since I messed with Folder Redirection last. Wonder when that got added.

Comment: I see it now in the policy.  Move the contents to the new location.  That's the behavior I want so that's awesome.

Comment: @Zoredache - put your answer as an Answer and I'll mark it correct.